# i want to use local storage to store the themes choosen by user

Tags: javascript, themes

Below is the Javascript code please help how to use local storage in this. Thanks

```js
var radios = document.getElementsByName('theme');

Array.from(radios).forEach( (el, i) => {
        
    el.addEventListener('change', e => {
            if(e.target.checked) {
                let value = e.target.getAttribute('value');
                    document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('data-theme', value);
                    document.documentElement.classList.add('in-transition')
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                      document.documentElement.classList.remove('color-theme-in-transition')
                    }, 1000)
                    
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)? If so, please include your attempt(s). -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the colors to an onclick function. After getting the color chosen by the user:

```js
function setActiveStyle(color){
    var currentColor = color // save the color in a variable to use else where
    localStorage.setItem("theme", color) // saves the theme chosen for future reference
```

You can get the color by using:

colorChosenByUser = localStorage.getItem("theme")

If you have many colors you can iterate through them and disable them to use the current theme chosen by the user. All this is assuming you have your html and css set up right.

Hope this helps.